# Best way to combine SIFT and ORB descriptors in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I need to combine `SIFT` and `ORB` descriptors of an image.

As you know, `SIFT` descriptors are of 128-length and `ORB` descriptors are of 32-length.

At this moment what I do is:

1. **Reshaping** `SIFT` descriptors to 32-length. For instance, reshape a (135, 128) descriptor to a (540, 32) descriptor
2. **Concatenating** `SIFT` and `ORB` descriptors (since at this moment both have 32-length)

Code:

```
sift_kp, sift_desc = sift.detectAndCompute(img,None)
new_sift_desc = sift_desc.reshape((int(128/32) * sift_desc.shape[0], 32))
orb_kp, orb_img_descriptor = orb.detectAndCompute(img,None)
all_descriptors = np.concatenate((new_sift_desc , orb_img_descriptor), axis=0)
```

I am wondering if there is a **better way** to combine these descriptors.

After combinating the descriptors, the idea is to use `all_descriptors` in order to perform feature matching against another image.

Comment: why don't you just concatenate them? you will end up with a 128+32=160 dimensional descriptor

Comment: Is it possible to concatenate arrays of different dimensions? If so, could you give me an example please?

Comment: `numpy.concatenate(array1, array2)`

Comment: I get this error -> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 128 and the array at index 1 has size 32

Comment: Think more about how to merge at all because ORB is binary descriptor and sift isnt. You probably wont be happy when either using binary distance metric with a part sift descriptor or euclidean distance with a part binary descriptor.

Comment: Maybe better compute similarity for each of the two descriptor pairs individually and use min or max or average of them.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to average :)

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-it-possible-to-combine-sift-and-orb-descriptors/7951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone is interested, what I have finally done is to use ORB in order to `detect` the images **keypoints** and use SIFT to `compute` **descriptors** from that keypoints

Code:

```
def get_orb_sift_image_descriptors(search_img, idx_img):
    # Initiate SIFT detector
    sift = cv.SIFT_create()
    # Initiate ORB detector
    orb = cv.ORB_create()
    # Find keypoints with ORB
    search_kp_orb = orb.detect(search_img, None)
    idx_kp_orb = orb.detect(idx_img, None)
    # Compute descriptors with SIFT
    search_kp_sift, search_des_sift = sift.compute(search_img, search_kp_orb)
    idx_kp_sift, idx_des_sift = sift.compute(idx_img, idx_kp_orb)
    return search_des_sift, idx_des_sift
```